# cupy cooperative_groups.h: [jitify] File not found

Tags: python-3.x, cuda, nvidia, cupy, cudatoolkit

```
from cupyx.scipy.signal import convolve2d as convolve2d_gpu

convolved_image_using_GPU = convolve2d_gpu(deltas_gpu, gauss_gpu)
%timeit -n 7 -r 1 convolved_image_using_GPU = convolve2d_gpu(deltas_gpu, gauss_gpu)


FutureWarning: cupyx.jit.rawkernel is experimental. The interface can change in the future.
  cupy._util.experimental('cupyx.jit.rawkernel')
cub/detail/detect_cuda_runtime.cuh(39): warning: cuda_runtime_api.h: [jitify] File not found
../util_type.cuh(42): warning: cuda.h: [jitify] File not found
cupy_jitify_exercise(10): warning: cooperative_groups.h: [jitify] File not found
cupy_jitify_exercise(11): warning: cooperative_groups/memcpy_async.h: [jitify] File not found
```

when i run the code i got above warnings...

i have reinstall cuda-toolkit, cupy but still this getting the warning. how to resolve this? i'm using Driver Version: 525.60.13, CUDA Version: 12.0

Comment: Are you on Windows? Does the code run and return correct results?

Comment: i am using ubuntu. yes the code returns correct result